# How to get the closing single quote in math mode

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

How to get the closing single quote in math mode. The apostrophe in math mode
is displayed as prime.

```
\documentclass{article}                                                              
\begin{document}                                                                     
Why can't I get $`a'$ in math mode.                                                  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should switch to text-mode, eg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Why can't I get $`a\textrm'$ in math mode
\end{document}
```

Comment: I find it is quite a good fix, but **one caveat**: for some formats you may get inconsistent results. For example, `\boldmath $\`a\textrm'$`shows the left quote bold, but the second not, because the second is set to standard roman. Just be aware. ;) By the way, egreg's solutions behaves correctly.

Comment: Can the quote be straight?

Answer (score 17):

Punctuation that is not part of a formula should go *outside* the formula:

```
When \(a>0\), we say that \(a\) is \emph{positive}.

In the interval \([0,1]\) there are infinitely many rational numbers.
```

It's quite rare that quotes are used as math symbols, but I've seen them in some textbook on mathematical logic. Since `'` is used for denoting a prime (dash) in math, one can resort to a different trick: the lines

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlq}{\mathord}{operators}{``}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrq}{\mathord}{operators}{`'}
```

will define two commands that will give left and right quotes in math and your input can become

```
Why can't I get $\mlq a\mrq$ in math mode.
```

but in this case `` `$a$' `` should be probably better.

I've added a companion to `\mrq` just for symmetry and, perhaps, greater clarity.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness.
A very flexible method to edit your equations is to step into **text mode** using the `amsmath` package command `\text{<your text>}`. Note that inside the `\text` command you can open new math environments. For example in the most simple case we might write: `` $\text{`$a$'}$ `` .

Admittedly, it looks a bit awkward, but in the example below it feels acceptable.

I also compare the `\text` solution with the `\mathrm` solution: `\mathrm` uses always the roman family (serif), but the function `\text` adapts the quotes to the family that is being used at the moment, for example *sans serif*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

We have equation serif \(\text{`$a$'}=20\) \(`a\textrm'=20\)
\sffamily We have equation sans \(\text{`$a$'}=20\) \(`a\textrm'=20\)

\end{document}
```

[image]