# Force printing of parentheses around a single character in math mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, punctuation

Although this is not strictly mathematical notation, I would like to denote an object with a calligraphy capital T and subscript non-italic P. I have this:

```
\newcommand{\timeP}{$\mathcal{T}_\mathsf{P}$}
```

That works fine, `\timeP` gives me T<sub>P</sub>. Now I need a variant where the `P` is surrounded by parentheses. But this:

```
\newcommand{\timePVirt}{$\mathcal{T}_{(\mathsf{P})}$}
```

just produces the same result as above. The desired result is T<sub>(P)</sub>.

Any ideas? A special escape character? My document uses package `amsmath`.

**EDIT**

Indeed the commentators are right---the parentheses should be there. It seems the problem is caused by the combination of these imports:

```
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

% --- Font choice
%     nightmare! leave alone for your own sanity
%     first choice roman is mathptmx - nice!
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

The second one `mathptmx` was in some document later imported through `\input` of the thesis template I was using, whereas I added `MnSymbol` directly to the `cls` file. Now when I reverse their order:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```

...the parentheses come back. I think I got the meaning of the comment `nightmare!`.

Comment: Your second definition of `\timeP`should create the desired result. Could you provide a complete (minimal) example that shows the problem?

Comment: @Martin. We'll very simple: `We call this time virtual or prospective performance time, denoted \timeVirt` -- with the above definition, the parentheses are just not printed, so there is no visible difference between `\timeP` and `\timePVirt`

Comment: Actually, I get the parenthesis when adding your definition to a minimalistic document. Thus, it would be helpful if you could provide a complete document, not just a part of it.

Comment: Sorry, that's a huge thesis template from my University :-/ I have a workaround though (posted as answer below)

Comment: Found the culprit---see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was

```
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

when changing to

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```

it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

The trick from [this question's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48742/how-to-get-the-closing-single-quote-in-math-mode) does it: escape with `\textrm`:

```
\newcommand{\timePVirt}{$\mathcal{T}_\mathsf{\textrm{(}P\textrm{)}}$}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\timePVirt}{$\mathcal{T}_{(\mathsf{P})}` will surely work. There's no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't here. I'm having `\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{uopthesis}` with a 400 lines template file, including some two dozen packages (geometry, titlesec, amsmath, setspace, graphicx, fancyhdr, biblatex, makeidx, nomencl, caption, subfig, paralist, fontenc, inputenc, color, rotating, lettrine, hyperref, hypercap, MnSymbol, babel)