# Quotation marks around operator in math mode

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

I want to create formulae where the `\rightarrow` is enclosed in double quotation marks and appears like any other word in a formula. What I'm getting instead, are formulae where these quotation marks are drawn to adjacent words, leaving a gap between the quotation marks and the `\rightarrow`.

Example: I'm getting `Some'' -> ''Word`. I want `Some ''->'' Word`.
The sequence `''->''` should be treated the same as `Some` or `Word`.
The `->` (`\rightarrow`) should be rendered as if it were used in an arbitrary math-environment.
I have looked at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63533/31877), but I could not turn that into something useful, as my MWE will show.
Also, I do not wish to break up my math environment, since the quotation marks are part of the formulae.

[image: bad rendering]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlq}{\mathord}{operators}{``}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrq}{\mathord}{operators}{`'}

\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
$Op \mapsto Op ``\rightarrow'' Op$%large gap on left; ' treated as prime

$Op \mapsto Op {``\rightarrow''} Op$%large gap on left; ' treated as prime

$Op \mapsto Op \mlq\rightarrow\mrq Op$%large gaps on left & right

$Op \mapsto Op {\mlq\rightarrow\mrq} Op$%large gaps on left & right

Quotation marks close\\
to arrow: ``$\rightarrow$''
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Enclose the `\rightarrow` in braces, as in `{\rightarrow}`.  Otherwise it is acting as a math operator.  The braces shield it from "operating" on the quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `\mlq` and so on as `\mathrel`, because TeX doesn't add space between consecutive relation symbols:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlq}{\mathrel}{operators}{``}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrq}{\mathrel}{operators}{`'}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlqq}{\mathrel}{operators}{"5C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrqq}{\mathrel}{operators}{`"}

\begin{document}

$Op \mapsto Op \mlq\rightarrow\mrq Op$

$Op \mapsto Op \mlqq\rightarrow\mrqq Op$

Quotation marks close to arrow: ``$\rightarrow$''
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need quotes around other symbols, you can follow a different path; declare the quotes as ordinary symbols (with `\mathord`) and define

```
\newcommand{\qto}{\mathrel{\mlq}\to\mathrel{\mrq}}
\newcommand{\qqto}{\mathrel{\mlqq}\to\mathrel{\mrqq}}
```

so you can have something like

```
$\mlq A\mrq \qqto \mlqq B\mrqq$
```

without worrying about spacings.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in my comment, you must enclose the `\rightarrow` in braces to shield it from operating on the surrounding quotation marks.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlq}{\mathord}{operators}{``}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrq}{\mathord}{operators}{`'}

\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
$Op \mapsto Op ``{\rightarrow}\mrq\mrq Op$%large gap on left; ' treated as prime

$Op \mapsto Op {``{\rightarrow}\mrq\mrq} Op$%large gap on left; ' treated as prime

$Op \mapsto Op \mlq{\rightarrow}\mrq Op$%large gaps on left & right

$Op \mapsto Op {\mlq{\rightarrow}\mrq} Op$%large gaps on left & right

\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted math "space" *outside* of the quote marks, you could make the whole group a `\mathrel`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlq}{\mathord}{operators}{``}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrq}{\mathord}{operators}{`'}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
$Op \mapsto Op \mathrel{``{\rightarrow}\mrq\mrq} Op$

$Op \mapsto Op \mathrel{\mlq{\rightarrow}\mrq} Op$
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]