# How to get single curved quotation marks in math mode

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

I know I can get these fancy quotes

```
`abc'
```

[image]

I want to get those quotes separately. I know how to get the left one:

```
{`}a
```

[image]

But when I try just the right one, I get a different quote then when used together:

```
abc{'}
```

[image]

How can I get the right curved one alone in math mode?

I am using `pdflatex`.

Comment: Can you please explain better? Aren't you getting single quotes with `\`abc'`?

Comment: @egreg edited. I get a different right quote when I use that one separately.

Comment: That's not the default behaviour for text mode. Perhaps some package is causing this. Can ypu please add a complete, minimla document, showing the undesired output?

Comment: You get a prime only in math mode. Is your aim to get a right quote in math mode? If so, please change the title and the text of the question accordingly.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I want this in math mode. edited accordingly.

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `$abc{\text{'}}$`.

Answer (score 9):

In math mode `'` produces a prime; to get the closing quotation mark in math mode you can use `\text` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$abc' \quad abc{\text{'}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In math mode, typing `'` is equivalent to typing `^{\prime}`, `''` to `^{\prime\prime}` and so on.

If you need “real” quotes in math mode, you have to define a math character for them. Typing `` ` `` is not guaranteed to give the desired result.

You can define

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlq}{\mathord}{operators}{``}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrq}{\mathord}{operators}{`'}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlq}{\mathord}{operators}{``}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrq}{\mathord}{operators}{`'}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlqq}{\mathord}{operators}{"5C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrqq}{\mathord}{operators}{`"}

\begin{document}
$\mlq a\mrq$

$\mlqq a\mrqq$
\end{document}
```

[image]

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161253/4427 for a similar setup, but in that case relations were concerned.