# Quotations in math mode using \enquote command from csquotes package

Tags: math-mode, quoting, csquotes

I'm using the `\enquote` command from the `csquotes` package for setting quotes.

When I invoke quotations inside math mode,
either by hand

```
``<some math>''
```

or by enquote

```
\enquote{<some math>}
```

it renders differently than in text mode.

Here's an example:

[image: Quotes Math Mode]

Can someone explain why this behavior occurs?

For adjusting the quotation marks by hand, I found [this workaround by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161253/54180).

How can I adjust the quotation marks invoked by enquote in math mode?

Here's a MWE, the one from above:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
In text mode:\\
Quote by hand: ``Blub''\\
Quote by enquote: \enquote{Blub}

In math mode:\\
Quote by hand: $``a^2+b^2=c^2''$\\
Quote by enquote: $\enquote{a^2+b^2=c^2}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\enquote{$formula$}` rather than `$\enquote{formula}$`, unless your quotes are part of the math. Are they?

Comment: Problem is I have it as something like `$\ldots \enquote{\ldots} \ldots$`. Do you have an idea what to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LaTeX issues one error and two warnings:

```
! Double superscript.
<recently read> ^

l.13 Quote by hand: $``a^2+b^2=c^2'
                                   '$
? 

LaTeX Warning: Command \textquotedblleft invalid in math mode on input line 15.

LaTeX Warning: Command \textquotedblright invalid in math mode on input line 15
```

Such errors and warnings should not be disregarded; it's a perhaps sad truth that `\textquotedblleft` in math mode produces a backslash, whereas `\textquotedblright` actually produces a closing double quote.

The error is because `'` in math mode is interpreted as `^{\prime}`, so `c^2'` indeed has a double superscript (the converse `c'^2` is instead legal, as is `c''^2`).

If you want to quote something in math mode, you should use math symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlq}{\mathord}{operators}{'134}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrq}{\mathord}{operators}{'42}

\begin{document}

$\dots\mlq\dots\mrq\dots$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, true that, it issues those warnings, completely didn't notice them, thanks! (Have it running in command prompt as `-interaction=batchmode` with `-file-line-error` only and checking for warnings only on an ad-hoc basis.)

Comment: Thanks, the integration worked **perfectly** with your solution and defining `\newcommand{\mathenquote}[1]{\mlq #1\mrq}`. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You have answered yourself: the quotes should be in the text mode:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
In text mode:\\
Quote by hand: ``Blub''\\
Quote by enquote: \enquote{Blub}

In math mode:\\
%Quote by hand: $``a^2+b^2=c^2''$\\
Quote by hand: ``$a^2+b^2=c^2$''\\

%Quote by enquote: $\enquote{a^2+b^2=c^2}$
Quote by enquote: \enquote{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Problem is that I need it as something like `$\ldots \enquote{\ldots} \ldots$`. Do you have an idea what to do?

Comment: `\ldots` work(s) also in the text mode. So `\ldots \enquote{\ldots} \ldots` will work.

Comment: Sorry, should have written `$<some formulas> \enquote{<formula>} <more formulas>$` and under different circumstances like labels in `tikzcd` and other situations.

Comment: If you use `amsmath`, you have a simple construction `\text\enquote{$...$}}`.

Comment: Do you think i can/is it good idea for me to redefine simply then \enquote as something like \ensuretextmode\enquote?