# Is there a way to get "dumb" single quote in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In mathmode, `'` gets converted to "prime" symbol.  What I'd like is neither the closing nor opening single quote as in ([How to get the closing single quote in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48742/how-to-get-the-closing-single-quote-in-math-mode)).  Rather, how do I get an unslanted neutral single quote in mathmode?

**To avoid any XY problem, I state here problem X:**

I am typesetting a document that uses Mathematica's font using the wrisym package.  After `\usepackage{wrisym}`, I can access all the Mathematica font in math-mode using `\mathversion{monobold}`.  But sometimes, I need the character that you get when you type `'` in the front end of the notebook, which is *not* the prime character.  How do I get LaTeX to output the unslanted `'` character.

---

**EDIT** Many thanks for everyone's prompt answers.  Please read below for a clear formulation of my problem.

```
\documentclass[a4,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage[uprightmonomath]{wrisym}

\DeclareMathVersion{monobold}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{monobold}{OML}{wcrum}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{monobold}{OT1}{wcrr}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{monobold}{OMS}{wcry}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

normal math:
$x y z$

Mathematica text:
\mathversion{monobold}$\sqrt{x}$\mathversion{normal}

symbol then quote:
\mathversion{monobold}$x'$\mathversion{normal}

\end{document}
```

generates:

[image]

Inputing the last two lines in *Mathematica*, it looks like:

[image]

Notice that the `'` character looks different in LaTeX than in the Mathematica notebook, because (I believe) it has been converted to a prime.

How do I get the raw `'` character in Mathematica font to appear in LaTeX so that it better approximates what appears in the Mathematica notebook?

Comment: Maybe `\textrm{'}`, as in `$A' \ne A\textrm{'}$`

Comment: Should this be in textmode? Maybe you could show us an example of expected output?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I cannot access the special fonts in text mode (which is why `\textrm{'}` doesn't work).

Comment: Then how about `\setbox0=\hbox{'}$A' \ne A\box0$`?

Comment: If you use it a lot, then `\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\sqcontent
\savebox\sqcontent{'}
\def\sq{\usebox{\sqcontent}}
\begin{document}
$A' \ne A\sq$
\end{document}`

Comment: @RunarTrollet See my edited question; I have tried to more clearly explain what I need.

Comment: @QuantumDot If you get any way of inputting such char (if you know it exist, and what slot it is in, you can do ``\begingroup\lccode`~=`'\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{<definition that outputs the upright prime>}`` and it wil correctly output whatever you put in that definition, so all you need is to get a way to output the symbol and with that code you will make `'` actually print it.

Comment: This comment won't bring any answer, but this seems more a font design question than a LaTeX question to me. In general, it seems straight single quote signs are more common in fixed width fonts. Furthermore, from the space between `x` and `'` in your last example, it seems to me that your output uses such a font (I can't test, I don't use mathematica). Lastly, from the very low quality images on [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html) page I conclude that mathematica uses a very ordinary single quote sign for derivatives.

Comment: @Manuel I came up with an alternative way to find the glyph, but I need a little help.  see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318358/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-all-the-glyphs-in-a-font

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt this is correct usage, but here is a solution using the `textcomp`-package.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,textcomp}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x\textnormal{\textquotesingle}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably `\textnormal` is better.

Answer (score 1):

Wether you define a command, and use it

```
\newcommand*\q{\mathchar`'}
$a\q b$
```

or if you want all `'` to give you the usual single text quote, you change the mathcode of `'` to not being “math-active” (active means `` \mathcode`'="8000 ``).

```
\mathcode`'=`' % this seems to work, but I'm not sure it's the perfect way
$a'b$
```

Comment: @QuantumDot It's not entirely clear to me if this is what you want, if you want the “upquote”, you can change the definition of the active `'` to whatever you want that outputs the upquote. You should edit your question and add some code or image.

Comment: I have expanded my question under "**EDIT**".  Perhaps it clearly explains what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think I came up with an alternative way to find what I need, but I need some help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318358/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-all-the-glyphs-in-a-font

Comment: Use `\xfonttable` as Ulrike said (and with other math encodings), and look for hte position of the glyph. If you pass a screenshot of the font table we can help you.

Comment: Thanks; Ulrike's suggestion helped, and the problem is now solved.

Comment: Post the answer here in that case, or add the screenshot and we can add an answer that lets `'` give you the glyph you want.