# How to obtain a list of all the glyphs in a font?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I am looking for a very specific symbol contained in the Mathematica font set: the raw unaltered single quote (see [Is there a way to get "dumb" single quote in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318256/is-there-a-way-to-get-dumb-single-quote-in-math-mode))

In the following code,

```
\documentclass[a4,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage[uprightmonomath]{wrisym}

\DeclareMathVersion{monobold}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{monobold}{OML}{wcrum}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{monobold}{OT1}{wcrr}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{monobold}{OMS}{wcry}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\singleGlyph}{\mathord}{symbols}{5}

\begin{document}

Mathematica glyph:
\mathversion{monobold}$\singleGlyph$\mathversion{normal}

\end{document}
```

output: [image]

I am able to inspect all the glyphs in the `wrisym` package one by one if I change the final integer (the `5`) in the command

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\singleGlyph}{\mathord}{symbols}{5}
```

to some other integer `6`, `7`, `8`, ... then recompiling to see what the 
glyph looks like.  But this is exceedingly time-consuming.

Is there a way to generate a document containing all the symbols/glyphs available in the font (including the integer associated with them)?  That way I can just pick the glyph I need.

Comment: You can e.g. use the fonttable package `\usepackage{fonttable}
... \xfonttable{OMS}{wcry}{b}{n}`, but this assumes that your glyph is encoded, if not you should look e.g. in the afm-file (if there is one).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This solves the problem; I am now able to pick out the symbols I need without trial and error.  Please post this as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can e.g. use the `fonttable` package

```
\usepackage{fonttable} 
... 
\xfonttable{OMS}{wcry}{b}{n}
```

but this assumes that your glyph is encoded, if not you should look e.g. in the afm-file (if there is one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `testfont.tex`. Use either:

```
tex testfont
```

or

```
pdftex testfont
```

Then give the name of the font file (pfb) without extension. For example if `cmr10.pfb`, use `cmr10`. Then you need to provide `\table` and `\end` as given in the below screenshot.

[image]